# Is there also an other relation that satisfies the trichotomous identity?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A relation $R$ on a set $A$ is called strict total order if it is total order and satisfies the trichotomous identity, i.e. if $R$ is:

- antireflexive, so $(\forall x \in A) \lnot(xRx)$ or $(\forall x \in A) <x,x> \notin R$
- antsymmetric, so $(\forall x \in A)(\forall y \in A) (xRy \rightarrow \lnot yRx)$ or $(\forall x \in A) (\forall y \in A) (<x,y> \in R \rightarrow <y,x> \notin R)$
- transitive, so $(\forall x \in A) (\forall y \in A) (\forall z \in A)(x Ry \wedge yRz \rightarrow xRz)$
- $(\forall x \in A)(\forall y \in A) \rightarrow xRy \lor yRx \lor x=y$

We can easily see that the trichotomous identity holds for  the following relations:

$$\langle_{\mathbb{R}}=\{\langle x,y \rangle \in \mathbb{R}^2: \text{ x is greater that y}\}$$

$$\langle_{\mathbb{R}}=\{\langle x,y \rangle \in \mathbb{R}^2: \text{ x is smaller that y}\}$$

Both of the above relations have to do with an inequality.

I was wondering if there is an other relation $R$, a one that is not related to $<$ or $>$ but satisfies the property:

$$(\forall x \in A) (\forall y \in A) (xRy \lor x=y \lor yRx)$$

Comment: Part of being a successful mathematician is to notice patterns. Have you noticed how pretty much whatever you post under [tag:set-theory] gets retagged? There is a pattern underlying that.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ok, I am sorry....

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are many other relations on $\Bbb R$ that are strict total orders.  Ones that do not come from the usual $\lt$ or $\gt$ are hard to describe.  I can certainly jumble up the pieces to make a new order, but the easy ways still use $\lt$ in the pieces.  For example, put $\Bbb Z$ in some order, say $0,1,-1,2,-2,3,-1,...$  Now we can say $xRy$ if $\lfloor x \rfloor$ comes before $\lfloor y \rfloor$ in the chosen ordering of $\Bbb Z$ or the floors are equal and the fractional part of $x$ is less than the fractional part of $y$.  Under the axiom of choice the reals can be well ordered, and in fact can be well ordered in many ways.  Each of them is a strict total order.